# Lookup of magic methods on old-style Python classes

Tags: python

I know old-style Python classes aren't recommended anymore, especially since Python 3 removes them.  However, I'd still like to understand what is happening here:

```
class MyClass:
  pass

my_instance = MyClass()
str(my_instance)
```

This snippet prints the following:

'<**main**.MyClass instance at 0x108ec4290>'

So, I don't have any explicit inheritance and I didn't overload the **str** method.  However, this doesn't raise an exception for the supposedly missing method.  Why?

I know that old-style classes have the concept of an 'instance' and a 'type' and that new-style classes aim to unify these concepts.  So is Python finding and calling the **str** method on the 'instance' type that my instance is implicitly connected to?

Here are some clues:

dir(my_instance) - Returns:

```
['__doc__', '__module__']
```

type(my_instance) - Returns:

```
<type 'instance'>
```

dir(type(my_instance)) - Returns:

```
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__call__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__coerce__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__iadd__', '__iand__', '__idiv__', '__ifloordiv__', '__ilshift__', '__imod__', '__imul__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__ior__', '__ipow__', '__irshift__', '__isub__', '__iter__', '__itruediv__', '__ixor__', '__le__', '__len__', '__long__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__oct__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__xor__', 'next']
```

Can anyone explain exactly the relationship between classes and types in old-style classes and what is happening here?

Comment: I might be making this up, but I recall that `__str__()` defaults to `__repr__()` if no `__str__()` is defined, and `__repr__()` defaults to something like what you show (`<main.MyClass instance at 0x108ec4290>`) if it's not overridden.

Comment: @jedwards: But even then, `__repr__` isn't there on the old style instance object either. So it would be the same magic... just one more hop.

Comment: @jedwards is right.  If that is the case, what 'magic' is happening to find the missing __repr__ method?

Comment: The same magic that happens to resolve all the special methods. I am just saying that whether it differs to repr first if not str exists doesnt really change the question.

Comment: @jdi, I agree -- was just making a sidenote, not critiquing your answer.

Comment: @jdi I agree.  I was just trying to say that if anyone knows the repr() magic it would also answer my question. :)

Comment: :-) just making conversation. Not like i had a fully concrete answer either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure other people can give you more concrete reasons that this, but there is a quote from a similar discussion located here: [old-style class](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/70403/old-style-class)

> `object` is the base class that is at the top of any inheritance tree.
>   The purpose of insisting on the base class, I believe, is to unify
>   object behavior without requiring too much 'magic.' That is, prior to
>   new-style classes, objects just magically had properties like `__doc__`
>   and `__str__`; now, they have them for a reason: because they inherited
>   them from the base class.

That part about the "magic" I believe is just that... black-box magic. Obviously the MRO (method resolution order) of old style classes was much more magical, in that it probably had to check both explicit definitions on the `instance` object, as well as on the `type`. Either that, or part of the mechanics of an old style class is to always provide a default `__str__` method when one cannot be located.

It would be less magical now with new-style classes, because due to the inheritance, the methods are really right there on the instance.

Here is another site with some good quotes and examples: [Principle of Biggest Surprise](http://segfaulthunter.github.com/articles/biggestsurprise/)

> For old-style classes all lookup is done in the instance.
>
> For instances of new-style classes, all special method lookup that is done implicitely is done in the class struct

**New-style:**

```
class Foo(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "old str"

foo = Foo()
foo.__str__ = lambda: "new str"

print str(foo)
print foo.__str__()

# old str
# new str
```

**Old-Style:**

```
class Foo:
    def __str__(self):
        return "old str"

foo = Foo()
foo.__str__ = lambda: "new str"

print str(foo)
print foo.__str__()

# new str
# new str
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the new-style snippet you showed above.  What is the difference between Python implicitly calling __str__ with str() and your direct call to __str__?  I would have thought both calls would print 'new str' since you replaced the __str__ method right?  Is this binding done before-hand and the object's __dict__ still has the old __str__ or something?

Comment: @durden2.0 - i updated the quote. It says on new style classes, implicit calls perform the lookup on the class. So str() is implicit.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  So all implicit lookups only look in the methods that are available in the class object, not the instance of the class?  How exactly does that work?  Does python somehow call the method with the class itself for implicit lookups?  It seems like this would still need an instance since it's not a static/class method, right?

Comment: I think the logic when you call `str(obj)` goes like this: Is `obj` an old-style instance? If so, call `obj.__str__()`. If no `__str__` method exists, do some black magic to return something anyway (this magic is one of the things that is undesirable about old-style instances). If `obj` is an instance of a new-style class, search the classes in its MRO until you find a `__str__` function to call. Since all new-style classes inherit from `object` (which has a `__str__` method), you're guaranteed to find an one, without any magic required.